OpenWebUI + Pipelines (w/ langchain hopefully)
I'm currently at the last step of https://github.com/open-webui/pipelines, and I tried to start the server, but it says the image below as my error. I'm not sure if the server is already running nor how to run a pipeline (like one of the examples) to test. Any advice would be greatly apprecieated!
error message
lutzy@Lutzy:~/pipelines$ sh ./start.sh
RESET_PIPELINES_DIR is not set to true. No action taken.
./start.sh: 43: [[: not found
PIPELINES_REQUIREMENTS_PATH not specified. Skipping installation of requirements.
./start.sh: 115: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

I was expecting no error message, and more information on the docs on how to run one of the example pipelines.

inline your error messages

It seems like issue between sh and bash invocations.
One of many answers from SO: here
Try :
bash ./start.sh

